# Cannot access windows share folder

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, windows-server-2008

In my windows domain, there's been happening a problem with the access to some of our shared folders:  There appears a "the account is disabled" problem whe trying to access those.

When looking at the the Active Directory Groups and Users snap-in, there's no user blocked nor disabled and the users trying to access the shared folders don't have any problem logging in on their respective computers. Needless to say, they have proper permissions on the network shares to be accessed.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid that message, It's necessary to go to Manage Credentials under user Accounts on Control Panel. It happens because some time in the past the username and password were stored and the account used to log in at that moment is now disabled. Deleting the past credentials will do the trick.